# Syncdb not installing south table

Tags: python, django, django-south

I get this when I run Syncdb

```
lex@lex-pc:~/projects/next$ ./manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django_filters

Not synced (use migrations):
 - django.contrib.auth
 - django.contrib.contenttypes
 - django.contrib.sessions
 - django.contrib.messages
 - django.contrib.staticfiles
 - django.contrib.admin
 - django.contrib.admindocs
 - south
 - etta
 - sorl.thumbnail
 - schlib
 - admin
 - gart
 - school1
 - school2
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

When I do `./manage.py migrate school1` I get `DatabaseError: relation "south_migrationhistory" does not exist`. 
The apps have migrations directory with migrations inside.
Is this an issue with south?

Comment: You need to do manage.py south before your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Am not sure if its the best practice.

What I did was to comment all the apps except `south`, Then `run ./manage.py syncdb --all`. The `south_migrationhistory` table was created then uncommented the apps and `run ./manage.py migrate` all the apps were `migrated`.